# Kotlin & Spring Boot - I have a MyBatis mapper that I'm "monkey patching" a method onto and need an autowired bean in the method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have an interface in Kotlin that is a MyBatis mapper:

```kotlin
@Mapper
interface EquipmentSupportMapper {
    // @Autowired lateinit var metaMapper: MetaMapper // <- Does not work... How?
    @SelectProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter::class, method = "select")
    fun findMany(selectStatement: SelectStatementProvider?): List<Equipment>
}
```

I then add a method implementation into it:

```kotlin
fun EquipmentSupportMapper.searchEquipment(
    textSearchValue: String? = null, facilities: Array<Int>? = null,
    manufacturers: Array<Int>? = null, equipmentExample: Equipment? = null
):
        List<Equipment> {
    val builder = SqlBuilder.select(equipmentColumnList)
        .from(EquipmentSupport.EquipmentTable)
        .where()
...
return someList;
```

Now, in my method `searchEquipment` I need to `@Autowire` a spring bean called `MetaMapper`.

I can't just add:

`@Autowired lateinit var metaMapper: MetaMapper` in the interface because it gives errors. How can I do this?

Comment: use abstract class instead of interface. Abstract class can have autowired properties

Comment: `No qualifying bean of type 'blah.EquipmentSupportMapper'` if I make it an abstract class annotated with `@Mapper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can do this:

```
@Mapper
@Qualifier("IESM")
interface InterfaceEquipmentSupportMapper {
    // @Autowired lateinit var metaMapper: MetaMapper // <- Does not work... How?
    @SelectProvider(type = SqlProviderAdapter::class, method = "select")
    fun findMany(selectStatement: SelectStatementProvider?): List<Equipment>
}

@Service
@Qualifier("EquipmentSupportMapper")
class EquipmentSupportMapper(
    @Autowired @Qualifier("IFSM") ifsm: InterfaceEquipmentSupportMapper,
    @Autowired metaMapper: MetaMapper
  ): InterfaceEquipmentSupportMapper by ifsm
```

The trick is to create a qualifier on the interface that Spring creates the implementation for and then inject that into the class that implements the same interface by delegating to the autowired Spring-created bean.

Then, instead of using the `Mapper` called *IESM* in my app I just autowire with the qualifier *EquipmentSupportMapper* instead and I get the right one.

Here's an example from a test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class EquipmentSupportMapperTest {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("EquipmentSupportMapper")
    lateinit var mapper: EquipmentSupportMapper
```